# How to see logs of cancelled steps in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a step in my workflow where I run a command (python script).
This python script appears to be hanging somewhere in the middle of the execution - GitHub shows the step as running it's stuck and nothing happens.

To debug this, I would want to see the log output of the python script. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking the dropdown arrow beside the action?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing.

Comment: I noticed that GitHub actions is not relaying the output from the command while the command is running. For other commands it seems to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [`Debug Logging`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) by adding secrets or environment variables (secrets take precedence if both set):

To debug a runner:

- **`ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG`** set to **`true`**

To debug each step:

- **`ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG`** set to **`true`**

Comment: This doesn't help, I see some setup debug output, but not the output of my script.