# How to see what Maven is sending to a server during deploy?

Tags: maven, github-actions, github-package-registry

I'm trying to use Github's new Actions CI server to deploy packages to Github's new packages feature. It's not going well.

I think it's all set up correctly, but I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy 
(default-deploy) on project myproject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not 
find artifact com.mycompany:myproject:pom:1.5 in github 
(https://maven.pkg.github.com/mycompany/mycompany_repository) -> [Help 1]
```

This happens *after* it appears to upload that same pom successfully:

```
Uploading to github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/mycompany/mycompany_repository
/com/mycompany/myproject/1.5/myproject-1.5.pom
Progress (1): myproject-1.5.pom (4.1/6.1 kB)
Progress (1): myproject-1.5.pom (6.1 kB)
```

So, it looks to me like it is successfully uploading the pom, but then it fails to download the same pom a few seconds later.

I'm running the deploy with debug switches on: `mvn -X -e deploy`, but I can't see the exact http commands that Maven is sending to the server.

How do I debug this? Is there some Maven/Aether transport or something that will log what is going on under the covers?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else lands here looking for a solution to OPs issue publishing to github, I had a similar issue and found that the URLs needed in settings.xml and pom.xml are inconsistent. In your settings.xml, the repo URL needs to be of the form *https://maven.pkg.github.com/myuser/com/mycompany/mypackage*, whereas in your project's pom file, it needs to be of the form *https://maven.pkg.github.com/myuser/mypackage*. So, for example, your settings.xml file in ~/.m2 would look something like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/myuser/com/mycompany/mypackage</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>myuser</username>
      <password>mypersonalaccesstoken</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Whereas the pom.xml file in the root of your project would need to look like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <groupId>org.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>mypackage</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>github</id>
      <name>GitHub Apache Maven Packages</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/myuser/mypackage</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

Other than this minor (but crucial) detail, my steps were the same as those outlined [here](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package). This allowed me to publish my Maven package to github package registry.

Comment: The settings.xml is shared between all the projects on your machine deployed by your user, so how could it have a url that is specific to a package from a specific project?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you would be expected to use your personal username in the file that would get checked in and re-used by all members of the team.

Comment: @Sherms Perhaps not, but the fact remains that it worked for me. Is your experience that software always works in a sensible manner?

Comment: @Jason - No, but Github obviously isn't expecting users working together as a team to tie a given project exclusively to their own private github account. 

I was eventually able to get this working with the org's name in every path so it does in fact work as expected/documented.

Comment: @Jason - Thank you for this suggestion here. Do you know if a similar issue exists in Azure DevOps repositories also? I am facing this similar issue but the structure of the Settings file is different ie. does not use profiles.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130154/unable-to-deploy-a-maven-jar-to-azure-do-repository)

Comment: @Mythbuster Maven and ADO are completely different animals and, as far as I know, no "Maven compatibility" layer exists on top of the ADO artifacts repo. I would try searching ADO-tagged questions for help with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [`debug logging`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/managing-a-workflow-run#enabling-debug-logging) in the workflows.

Just add the secret:

```
ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG
```

And set to true

*See a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58989736/2089675)*

Answer (score 1):

I just spend 3 hours debugging why the guide on the page did not work for me. If you are following the guide posted here [1](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package).

OWNER is your github username, and REPOSITORY is - you guessed it, the repo name.

Just remember to use lowercase in both OWNER and REPOSITORY.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

1. Create a repository for packages e.g. `maven-packages`
2. Add `<server></server>` settings under `<servers>` in `settings.xml`: (do this per id used below)

```xml
    <server>
        <id>github</id>
        <username>YOUR GITHUB USERNAME</username>
        <password>A GITHUB TOKEN YOU CREATE FOR PUBLISHING PACKAGES</password>
    </server>
```

3. Do **NOT** add `<activeProfiles>`, `<profile>` or `<repositories>` to `settings.xml` (**only add `<server>` elements**) as this is redundant for publishing and I am adding them to consuming projects' `maven.xml` so no need for duplication.
4. Add repository/ies to `distributionManagement` in `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>github-snapshot</id>
            <name>GitHub snapshot</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/maven-packages/</url>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>github-release</id>
            <name>GitHub release</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/maven-packages/</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Where `OWNER` is the GitHub account your project is / projects are under and `maven-packages` is the repositories you want to publish you project(s) to.

This enables using a dedicated repository for listing packages instead of publishing each project's package to a different (its own) repository, making consumption of multiple packages from your GitHub account easier, as you only need to configure a single repository for these packages:

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/maven-packages/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Note: in the `<servers>` section of your `settings.xml` define a `<server>` per `id` used in `repositories` and `distributionManagement` e.g. `github-snapshot`, `github-release`, `github` in the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

When generating the personal access token, make sure the scopes for the token are the repo:* scopes as well as the more obvious write:packages and read:packages scopes (do not disable the repo scopes)

Otherwise it does just that