# GitHub packages: Single Maven repository for GitHub organization

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, package-management, github-package-registry

I would like to use GitHub packages to store Maven artifacts for several repositories in a GitHub organization. [Currently](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages), it appears that for each project, a separate (Maven) repository configuration entry is required to point to that (GitHub) repository's Maven repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>github</id>
  <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
  <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
</repository>
```

The corresponding configuration for the Maven project that would be published is:

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>github</id>
     <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Is there a way to configure the packages to all go to a single REPOSITORY? Setting the REPOSITORY to either a different existing or non-existing (GitHub) repository in the organization fails the build, as does removing the /REPOSITORY entirely

Comment: If you really want to have it available to the public i would recommend to go to central repository instead of github package https://central.sonatype.org/

Comment: What'st the content of your workflow? Have you created a PAT with read and write access to the organization's packages and are you using this in your workflow?

Comment: @riQQ currently, we have GitHub actions that publish the artifacts to GitHub packages, and wish to consume them for local development as well as within GitHub packages. Have generated a PAT for local read access, using the built in token in Actions to publish

Comment: The built in token only has access to the repository the workflow is running in. Try using a PAT with access to the organization's packages.

Comment: @riQQ using a PAT I am able to _access_ the org's packages, but cannot publish with the PAT to any other REPOSITORY, or to the root (without the /REPOSITORY qualifier). I can however publish with the PAT to the current repository

Comment: It looks like the Packages tab on an organization just aggregates the packages of the organization's repositories (see https://github.blog/2019-05-10-introducing-github-package-registry/) and there's nothing in the documentation hinting at "organization wide" packages.

Comment: I have been trying this myself by uploading from another Maven Java project to upload to another Github repo.  It does not work whether I use a Pat or Github token.

Comment: @IvanG did you get it working in the end?

Answer (score 7):

For people who are just looking to avoid specifying the `<repository>` tag multiple times:

Apparently, GitHub **DOES NOT** care about what repository you set when pulling packages from the Registry. When pulling, **the package index is based on the organization level, not the repository level**.

You can just do this if you want to pull packages **from multiple repositories that are within the same organization**:

```
<repository>
  <id>github</id>
  <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
  <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/Your-Orgnazation/JUST-ENTER-ANYTHING-HERE</url>
</repository>
```

**NOTE:** You still need the Personal Token to pull the packages across repositories. You just don't have to specify the `<repository>` tag multiple times.

Comment: >JUST-ENTER-ANYTHING-HERE
indeed, thanks, just make sure that you (or that user/bot whose token you use for build) have access to the package you are trying to pull

Answer (score 5):

## Personal Access Token

`secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` is defined by default but it is only sufficient to deploy to the current repository.

To make it work across repositories you'll need to define a new Personal Access Token in:

- `Settings` > `Developer Settings` > [`Personal Access Tokens`](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Select `write:packages` for the scope and all the `repo` scopes should be automatically selected for you.

[image]

## Repository / Organisation secrets

Next, define a secret in your organisation or each of the repositories you need to publish packages from.

Give it a name (i.e. `DEPLOY_GITHUB_TOKEN`) and set its value to the Personal Access Token created in the previous step.

[image]

Repository secrets are defined in repository `Settings` > `Secrets`. There's a similar section for the organisation.

## GitHub Action

Finally, make sure you pass your Personal Access Token to the deployment step as an environment variable called `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

In the example below, it's set to the value of the `DEPLOY_GITHUB_TOKEN` secret defined in the previous step.

```yaml
name: Build

on:
  release:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build & Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots install

      - name: Deploy to GitHub
        run: mvn --batch-mode -DskipTests -DuseGitHubPackages=true deploy
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Since I used a dedicated Maven profile for the GitHub package repository distribution management, I also activated it with `-DuseGitHubPackages=true`.

## Maven profile

In the profile example below, I configured distribution management to use the external/shared repository `vlingo/vlingo-platform` just like suggested in @Danny Varod's answer.

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<project>
  <!-- ... -->

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>useGitHubPackages</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/vlingo/vlingo-platform</url>
        </repository>
      </distributionManagement>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Cross posted from: https://dev.to/jakub_zalas/how-to-publish-maven-packages-to-a-single-github-repository-3lkc

A working example can be found in vlingo repositories: https://github.com/vlingo/vlingo-platform/packages

Comment: Hi @Jakub Zalas, I followed the same approach as mentioned in that post. But I'm getting this error ->
```Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project demoproject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.example:demoproject:jar:3.0.1 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/******/test-platform) -> [Help 1]```. Could you please help with this? Thank you.

Comment: I also added the Personal Access Token to the secrets of repo with the same scope as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this a while back by creating an empty repository named maven-packages or something like that and publishing all the Maven packages from all the organization's repositories to this one repository.

This enabled configuring a single Maven repository (in addition to Maven-central) locally, on build machine and in deployment environment for pulling Maven-library dependencies.

I don't have this code (was at a previous workplace and now I use Python), however, I recall using the `mvn deploy` command line for this as [documented here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html):

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=<path-to-pom> \
  -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

and I modified the pom.xml during the build to insert the correct deploy repository's details, so the publishing could only be done via the build (and to add pre-release details to the pre-releases' version number). This also enabled adding an additional repository for external stable releases (to be published to Maven-central).

See configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398972/38368).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Deployment works fine within a single repository, but as soon as I change the url to an external one (not the current repo), all I get is "422 Unprocessable Entity". Even if the personal access token was set up with all the repo and package permissions.

Comment: I last used this about a year ago and don't have access to the workflow. Did you try the configuration answer link I added? Github also has good support.

Comment: In the end, I deleted the repository, created it again, and everything started to work... Seems that my initial attempts messed something up and it wasn't possible to resolve without re-creating the repo.

Comment: @JakubZalas I did not get this working yet. Can you share your solution as a separate answer if it is significantly different than Danny's, or otherwise explain what needed to happen for it to work?

Comment: @IvanG. The solution is very similar. For now, I've got it on a fork of the project I want to implement it for. Packages are published to https://github.com/jakzal/vlingo-platform/packages. One of the commits that introduced github publishing: https://github.com/jakzal/vlingo-actors/commit/14978fc71b6da7f8c4fa5666d60e36dc7d483d9a

Comment: @JakubZalas did you define the `env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}`?

Comment: @DannyVarod the default token will only work if you need to publish to the current repo. If you want to publish to a different one you'll need to define a new user access token. I called it `DEPLOY_GITHUB_TOKEN`, defined as a secret, and passed to the step: `env: GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_GITHUB_TOKEN }}`.

Comment: @JakubZalas either add this as an answer or edit mine.