# Organisation-Wide repositories with GitHub Packages & Maven

Tags: maven, github-package-registry

If I have a GitHub organisation **ACME**, and we have two repositories **Repository1** and **Repository2** which both publish packages to GitHub packages via Maven, is there a way to have both packages be added in a single Maven repository, as an organisation owner?

For instance,

```xml
<!-- settings.xml -->
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>github</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/ACME</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Install a repository manager and handle it with it...it's easier more flexible than package on Github...

Comment: Yes, this works, you need to create a dummy repo for publishing to (and pulling from) for the packages. Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63041402/38368