# Unable to deploy a Maven jar to Azure DO repository

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I am unable to deploy a standalone jar file in Azure devops repository. Using the following command to invoke the deploy plugin on maven:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging="jar" -DrepositoryId="MAVENREPO" -Durl="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/q6f55433-87d0-4c87-a6ab-7d5c19f9088b/_packaging/MAVENREPO/maven/v1" -DgroupId="agile" -DartifactId="AgileAPI" -Dversion="1.0" -Dfile="AgileAPI.jar"
```

And I am getting the following error. It appears that the file is being uploaded to Azure repository but somehow failing to deploy. Any pointers will be appreciated.

I have tried this both with a maven command as shown above and with the pom.xml file invoking the deploy plugin. The result is the same.

```
Uploading to MAVENREPO: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/q6f55433-87d0-4c87-a6ab-7d5c19f9088b/_packaging/MAVENREPO/maven/v1/agile/AgileAPI/1.0/AgileAPI-1.0.jar
Uploading to MAVENREPO: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/q6f55433-87d0-4c87-a6ab-7d5c19f9088b/_packaging/MAVENREPO/maven/v1/agile/AgileAPI/1.0/AgileAPI-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.221 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-09T21:21:43-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact agile:AgileAPI:jar:1.0 in MAVENREPO (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/q6f55433-87d0-4c87-a6ab-7d5c19f9088b/_packaging/MAVENREPO/maven/v1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

The command to publish a 3rd party assembly to a Maven feed in Azure Artifact is as below:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging="jar" -DrepositoryId="MyFeedName" -Durl="MyFeedURL" -DgroupId="MyGroup" -DartifactId="myFirstApp" -Dversion="jarFileVersion" -Dfile="jarFileLocalPath"
```

I've tested on my side with the Maven artifact generated by running the following command:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="org.apache.maven.archetypes" -DgroupId="MyGroup" -DartifactId="myFirstApp"
```

and got a successful result with the command below:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dpackaging="jar" -DrepositoryId="{MyFeedName}" -Durl="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org}/TestCase/_packaging/{MyFeedName}/maven/v1" -DgroupId="MyGroup" -DartifactId="myFirstApp" -Dversion="1.0-SNAPSHOT" -Dfile="C:\Users\{username}\myFirstApp\src\main\java\MyGroup\App.java"
```

Notice:

You need:

1 . Add the `settings.xml` file in `${user.home}/.m2`:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>[MyFeedName]</id>
      <username>[ORG]</username>
      <password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

2 . Add the repo to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<repository>
  <id>[FEEDNAME]</id>
  <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECTNAME}/_packaging/{FEEDNAME}n/maven/v1</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

You could follow my step, to see whether you specify wrong parameter in the command.

Useful blog:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/maven/publish?view=azure-devops

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?